# Dynamic PropertyInjection in an Apache Camel Bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, apache-camel

I'm using the **@PropertyInject** annotation to get properties from the application.properties file to use in my beans.
This normally works fine, but now I need to be able to change the injected property based on a header value.
In my head it looks something like this:

```
@PropertyInject(PROPERTY_NAME)  
private String property;

public void pickProperty(String msgVersion) {
        if (msgVersion.equals("A")) {
            PROPERTY_NAME = "property.firstType.name";  
        } else {
            PROPERTY_NAME = "property.secondType.name";
        }
    }
```

I've considered just injecting both properties and deciding in the main method which one to use, but that seems like a roundabout way of doing things and will get a bit bloated if more versions are added.
Is there an easy way this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now I need to be able to change the injected property based on a header value

**Properties and Beans are created on application startup** and typically do not change while the application is running. They both have application scope.

Header values on the other hand **can change for every message that is processed** by your application.

As you suggested yourself: You can inject both properties into the Bean and provide a method that is called once per message to get the correct value

```
@PropertyInject(PROPERTY_A)  
private String propertyA;
@PropertyInject(PROPERTY_B)  
private String propertyB;

// called for every message processing
public String pickProperty(@Header("msgVersion") String msgVersion) {
    if (msgVersion.equals("A")) {
        return propertyA;
    } else {
        return propertyB;
    }
}
```

This is not at all a workaround, but simply a method that returns a different result based on the input.